# Elliptic curve $E$ and $E^{ \Bbb σ}$ is isom as schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $ \sigma \neq{id} \in Aut(\Bbb{C})$ and $E^{ \Bbb σ}$ be galois conjugate of $E$(elliptic curve gained by action of $ \sigma$ to coefficients of $E$).

Then, $E$ and $E^{ \Bbb σ}$ is not isom as algebraic variety over $ \Bbb{C}$ because their $j$ invariant is not the same.

But I heard $E$ and $E^{ \Bbb σ}$ are isom as schemes.

How can I confirm(prove) that fact ?

THank you in advance.

Comment: Can you do this for other schemes (even affine, if you want)?

Comment: It is about the field of definition. $\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-ix-1)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+ix-1)$ as $\Bbb{R}$-algebra but not as $\Bbb{C}$-algebra. Such an isomorphism can't be given by a rational map $\Bbb{C^2\to C^2}$. 

Now $\Bbb{R}[x,y,z]/(y^2-x^3-zx-1,z^2+1),\Bbb{R}[x,y,z]/(y^2-x^3+zx-1,z^2+1)$ makes both curves defined over $\Bbb{R}$ (as subvarieties of $\Bbb{A^3(R)}$) and the isomorphism is given by a rational map $\Bbb{R^3\to R^3}$: $(x,y,z)\to (x,y,-z)$.